# MDX is not quite right..need to filter parents and their siblings

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssas, mdx, business-intelligence

**Goal**: Remove all levels above the specified user access level.

**Example**: I have a user in the where clause who has access to district 3717. Under that district, there are few departments (blacked out in the picture). I am trying to make a query that lists District 3717, departments listed under district 3717, and sibling of that district for that region only (district 3701 to 3718).

**What I have right now**: I have a query that lists District 3717, departments listed under district 3717, and sibling of that district for that region only (district 3701 to 3718). ALSO, it lists its parents, all the regions, for that area (area 3), Area 3 and its siblings, (Area 3, 4, 5), Company, Deleted, Invalid, and ALL.

I am trying to modify the aggregate part of the query but not getting anywhere.

**Highlighted** in the screenshot is the only that that I am interested in. If the user has access to Region 35, I want the result set to have Region 30 to 39, Districts only under Region 35, and departments under all districts only under region 35.
Please refer to the image.
Please help

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterValue] AS
    [Organization].[Organization Hierarchy].CurrentMember.UniqueName
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterCaption] AS
    iif([Organization].[Organization Hierarchy].CurrentMember.Level.Ordinal =1,"",[Organization].[Organization Hierarchy].CurrentMember.Properties( "Organization Id" ) + " - ") +
    [Organization].[Organization Hierarchy].CurrentMember.Name  
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterLevel] AS
        [Organization].[Organization Hierarchy].CurrentMember.Level.Ordinal
MEMBER [Measures].[User Count] AS
    [Measures].[User Organization Count]
    -
    Aggregate(
        {[Organization].[Organization Hierarchy].parent
        ,DESCENDANTS([Organization].[Organization Hierarchy])}
        ,[Measures].[User Organization Count]
    )
SELECT 
{
    [Measures].[ParameterValue]
    ,[Measures].[ParameterCaption]
    ,[Measures].[ParameterLevel]
}
ON COLUMNS,
FILTER
(
    DESCENDANTS([Organization].[Organization Hierarchy],5, SELF_AND_BEFORE)
    ,[Measures].[User Count]
)
ON ROWS
FROM [Cube]
WHERE
(
[Users].[User Name].&       [User_with_access_to_district_level__this_user_is_assgined_to_district_3718],
[Organization].[Organization Hierarchy Name].&[typeofhierarchy]
)
```

[image: Please refer to this image.]

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to build the set you want using a UNION.

```
UNION
(
    //This bit gets you the children (districts)
    DESCENDANTS([Organization].[Organization Hierarchy].&[35],1, AFTER),
    //This bit gets you the siblings, including self
    [Organization].[Organization Hierarchy].&[35].SIBLINGS
)
ON ROWS
```

Comment: So instead of using 
FILTER
(
    DESCENDANTS([Organization].[Organization Hierarchy],5, SELF_AND_BEFORE)
    ,[Measures].[User Count]
)
I should use, 
FILTER
(
 Union {DESCENDANTS([Organization].[Organization Hierarchy],1, After), 
    [Organization].[Organization Hierarchy].SIBLINGS}
    ,[Measures].[User Count]
) 
?

Comment: Yes and no, I think you are trying to put two different sets together into one - the siblings of the one you are after and the children. Not sure why you are trying to add the FILTER statement back in, though.

Comment: But I ma filtering data based on Descendants and Usercount...can you suggest an alternative that would do the same?